# How to get sum of previous year's total with the next year total

Tags: php, mysql

I have a below query

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT id ) AS `total` , YEAR( created_date ) AS `memberYear`
FROM `users` AS `u`
WHERE (
role_id =2
AND is_deleted =0
AND is_trashed =0
)
GROUP BY `memberYear`
```

With this query i am getting record like this

```
total   memberYear
 10        2012 
 12        2013 
 2         2014
```

Now i need to get record total sum with previous year

```
total   memberYear sumTotal
10        2012       10
12        2013       22
2         2014       24
```

How can i get this sum of Total ? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The COUNT is returning you the total number of users for that perticular year... what do you want to achieve...

Comment: Suppose i have count of users in 2012 is 10, Now in year 2013 count of user is 12. So in 2013 total should be 10+12 = 22. I want to get this kind of total

Comment: This could probably done in one query but I don't know how *not this early in the morning; I need a 2nd cup of coffee for it*. Off the top of my head, you could do it in PHP and do two queries, by merely adding them both up. `$total = $query1 + $query2;`

Comment: This is called a **running total**. It's not hard to out how to do this in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a try with this one:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT id ) AS `total` , YEAR( created_date ) AS `memberYear`,
@running_total := @running_total + COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS total
FROM `users` AS `u`
, (SELECT @running_total := 0) var_init_subquery
WHERE (
role_id =2
AND is_deleted =0
AND is_trashed =0
)
GROUP BY `memberYear`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only do that with mysql if you use a stored procedure, or use a nested select, but I would not recommend it. Since you use PHP, and already have the query response, just add the current year value to the previous one's :

```
$sumTotal=0;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $sumTotal+=$row["total"];
}
```

Comment: this seems pretty unlogical to me to be honest.

Comment: It is more than logical to me. Why use a nested select, when you already have all that you need in the results ?

Comment: but the $sumTotal and $previousYearValue .. why in earth would you need both, you can do it by only using the $sumTotal value

Comment: yes, that is true, I thought that he only needed the sum of the current and previous year. I changed the code, thank you @Azrael

Comment: okay, now you can have my upvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the cumulative sum. Unfortunately mysql does not yet support window functions which makes such things real easy. One way is to use a theta self join like:

```
SELECT X.memberYear, sum(y.total)
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT id ) AS `total` , YEAR( created_date ) AS `memberYear`
    FROM `users` AS u
    WHERE role_id =2
      AND is_deleted =0
      AND is_trashed =0
    GROUP BY memberYear
) AS x 
JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT id ) AS `total` , YEAR( created_date ) AS `memberYear`
    FROM `users` AS `u`
    WHERE role_id =2
      AND is_deleted =0
      AND is_trashed =0
    GROUP BY `memberYear`
) y
   on y.memberyear <= x.memberyear
group by X.memberYear
```

This is untested, so there might be some errors in there.